# Backend Handlebars select tag

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, html-select

I am building an advanced searching operator for my app. I am trying to get the parameters of the search to persist through the search. My problem is that I have `<select>` tags so I can't just pass the value through.

```
<select name="sort" value="{{inputs.sort}}">
            <option value="None" >None</option>
            <option value="NAME">Alphabetical</option>
            <option value="RATING">Rating</option>
            <option value="RELEVANCE">Relevance</option>
        </select>
```

the value attr doesn't work with the select tag. The only way I've found to do this is by putting the selected attr inside of the option tags `<option selected="selected">...<option>`, but there is no simple way to do this with handlebars.

helpers don't work because I am only using backend handlebars which doesn't allow ternaries. Apart from completely generating the HTML from the backend I can't find a way to do this but I feel like there has to be a "clean" or "dry" solution.

Comment: Can use `data-value` and update the select when page loads from it's dataset